# How can i use requestAnimationFrame instead of translate3d?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Due to behaviour of browser where translate3d renders vector elements as textures I now need to use simple 2d translate, however this means that performance is harmed. I tried to find a solution and `requestAnimationFrame` came up, but I can't figure out how to use it in my case:

```
$document.bind(events['move'], function(e) {
                    $('.slide-panel.shown').find('.close-panel').trigger('click');
                    var valueX = getTransform($elem,'posX'),
                        valueY = getTransform($elem,'posY'),
                        zoom = getTransform($elem,'zoom'),
                        translateX,
                        translateY;
                    if (is_touch_device()) {
                        translateX = valueX + (e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX - mouse.x);
                        translateY = valueY + (e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY - mouse.y);
                    } else {
                        translateX = valueX + (e.pageX - mouse.x);
                        translateY = valueY + (e.pageY - mouse.y);
                    }

                    $elem.css({
                        'transform': 'translate3d(' + translateX +'px, ' + translateY +'px, 0) scale('+zoom+')',
                        '-webkit-transform': 'translate3d(' + translateX +'px, ' + translateY +'px, 0) scale('+zoom+')',
                        '-moz-transform': 'translate3d(' + translateX +'px, ' + translateY +'px, 0) scale('+zoom+')'
                    });
                    console.log($elem.css('transform'))
                        mouse.update(e);
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
```

There is a lot involved, but essentially this is part of my drag and drop code that uses translate3d to move element around, I need to somehow get rid of translate3d and use just translate but within animation frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think requestAnimationFrame is going to solve your performance problems here.

You're using a event handler which is searching for elements on every 'tick'. What you could do is cache the elements you request from the DOM:

```
(function () {
    var $closeElement = $('.slide-panel.shown').find('.close-panel');

    $document.bind(events['move'], function(e) {
        $closeElement.trigger('click');

        // rest of your animation code.
    });
}());
```

How many events are fired when you're moving?

If there are a lot of events you could try throttling the animation. Remy Sharp has a great article on how to do this:
https://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use translate3d() with 3rd argument z=0 and use it normally like translate().

Or use it like translate3d(0,0,0) to force hardware boost and then use simple translate() for moving. All translate functions are acceleratable but translate3d() function seems to force browser to use GPU.

You can can of course use reqestAnimationFrame() for recursively calling some function to change elements just before the screen redraw that will give you best possible performance. But if you also want some easing, which is easily achieved in CSS through 'ease' argument in 'animation' property, in your animation you will implement it yourself creating maybe some time based functions. [Here][1] is the examples of what I am talking about.

Comment: Here it is http://www.kirupa.com/html5/animating_with_easing_functions_in_javascript.htm